# Hide a grid's column ( backend )

Tags: admin, grid, grid-serlization, column

I just want to have the column in the grid but not visible.

Is it possible ? any parameter I should pass to addColumn()

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You column can look like this:

```
$this->addColumn('column_id_here', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('helper_name_here')->__('Column header here'),
    'index' => 'column_index_here',
    'column_css_class'=>'no-display',//this sets a css class to the column row item
    'header_css_class'=>'no-display',//this sets a css class to the column header
));
```

Basically, you can use `column_css_class` and `header_css_class` to add any CSS classes to the column and then work your magic in the CSS file. In Magento admin default theme `no-display` class has 'display:none' on it.

Comment: It create problem when you have empty grid.It count non display column in colspan so design mess up when no record found.