# URLl to custom grid with filtering choose (not ui_component grid)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid

How can I build URL to custom grid, so when I enter it some filtering is already applied. Magento 2.05. Grid is not ui-component one. I tried some answer for Magento 1.7 but did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613972/how-to-link-to-a-custom-grid-with-pre-applied-filters) works as well in Magento 2. One thing to note - if you have field to be filtered in your collection, but there is no column for it in grid, filtering will not work.

If you want to filter, but still don't want that column, you can hide it using some of its css propierties, just like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/hide-a-grids-column-backend)